Using generative AI at work
I am using generative AI quite a bit at work to form letters to customers and to write reports.
Each time I check the work created and happily put my name to the piece. I will take responsibility if I get it wrong.
What are my moral and employee responsibilities with regards to informing my bosses that I am using generative AI tool(s)?

The biggest issue I see here is that you are probably sending internal information to an external company. True, openAI (or whoever) won't make any use of it, but likely your company has (or should have) a policy regarding it. For the other aspects, AI is a tool, as long as you are responsible for what you are producing, there is no problem.

"openAI (or whoever) won't make any use of it" Yes, OpenAI or whoever absolutely 100% will make use of any information you give them unless your company has an legal agreement with them not to.

To give a concrete example of other's comments have a read of https://www.techradar.com/news/samsung-workers-leaked-company-secrets-by-using-chatgpt - any data you send to an AI service normally gets absorbed into its model, and can potentially be incorporated into responses it generates for any other user. Check your company IT security policy and make sure the data you're sending isn't private or confidential, and / or that the service agreement for the AI service you're using doesn't do this...

@PhilipKendall - OpenAI can use what you use, unless you have a paid account, and you then select the option NOT to actively remember previous conversations. If you are not a paid user, then OpenAI absolutely is using what you sent them.

@ColinLangdon - I hope you realized that the fact you are using a Gen AI to generate your letters to customers and reports is likely obvious to many people. As a customer I wouldn't be impressed by any response from a company that was obviously genrated by a GenAI.

It is very important to double and triple check what AI is generating. I received several marketing emails that were clearly generated by AI as they included a number of details that were false. "We were particularly impressed by your actions on X." when I had nothing to do with X.

@mclayton I don't believe that the model absorbs information from the requests. Do you have any source for that? If so, it would be very easy to "hack" the model by  sending false information. Conversations, AFAIK, are not used in the training.

@PhilipKendall Yes, you are right, I should have said that probably openAI is not going to use the data OP is sending in a way to harm OP's company. They might use them for other purposes, but I doubt that they will actively sell internal information to competitors

@nicola - I don't have any references - I based my comment on how I thought I knew they worked. Depends on the ToS of the specific service I guess, so read the small print carefully - caveat emptor...

@PhilipKendall - “Can’t” OpenAI cannot or they say they won’t if it’s a paid account. At least that’s what the Terms of Service state.

@Donald Before Gen AI, companies used form letters, where the employee would pick one out of 10-50 canned responses and substitute the customer's name and numbers. LLM responses are a considerable step up from that.

@Therac I'd rather have the form letters.  They'll at least be proofread for accuracy.  GenAI just makes shit up.


what are my moral and employee responsibilities with regards to
informing my bosses that I am using AI

I think it's your professional responsibility to make your supervisor or boss aware of any new tool(s)/service(s) that you intend to use at work.
Most importantly, it is important to ensure you boss is either aware of or fully understand the implications of using a generative AI tool, the data that will get shared and possible implications thereof.

There are two sides to this:
Firstly, in terms of moral obligation, opinion may differ, but my thought is so long as the work is getting done in a safe manner, that is all that matters. There is nuance in this answer - there are times when there are other concerns - but for the purposes of drafting letters or reports, most of those nuances are unlikely to be applicable.
That brings us to the professional obligations, and the big one here is DATA. My company has policy around AI usage, and the TL;DR is: Do not feed it anything that is (or could be) commercially sensitive.
And there are things in letter drafting and reports that absolutely could be sensitive.
This is where you need to have a conversation internally about whether what you are doing is acceptable for the company.
Some companies might be okay with it. Some might want to put policy in place around it. Some might simply decide the risk is too great for a new and emerging tech and ban your usage of it (which you will have to accept).
But yes - because of the risk of putting sensitive data into a LLM, you need to have the discussion with management.


what are my moral and employee responsibilities with regards to informing my bosses that I am using AI ?

It does not hurt to ask your boss if it is OK to use AI to create a letter. If he says it is OK, then you can keep using AI.
Of  course, it may be a very good idea to double-check and possibly edit a few words, lines or even small paragraphs in the letter that is generated by AI. Make sure that letter does not sound too fancy or inappropriate to your business and customers.

Are we sure it won’t hurt the author? If the author outputs can be performed by GenAI why does the company need th me author? Just saying..It’s being done all over..ChatGPT is just good enough and cheaper then a person when answering customer questions that customer service departments are shrinking as a result
